# Crystal Report Grouping issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table like this:

```
Prod   Unit    Name  
A      1       X1  
B      2       X2  
A      3       X3  
B      4       X4
```

Now I am grouping it by Prod column.

I want all Distinct Unit column values in group Header, something like this:

```
Group header: **PROD**: A **Unit**:1,3  
Detail: X1   
        X3  
Group Header: **PROD**: B **Unit**:2,4  
Details: X2  
         X4
```

Please let me know any possible way to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done.

- Insert a group on `Unit`
- Suppress GH1 and GF1
- Create a manually, running-total field to serialize the `Unit` (there are so many examples of this, that I won't repeat the process)
- Add a text field with the text '**PROD**: '; insert the G1-name field into the text field
- Do the same for the '**Unit**' field; insert the formula that holds the serialized values